# How to get a src image via js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to get the src image and bind it to my img tag, I'd create it in JS file and I imported, but nothing happened, first file is About.vue and the second one is my utils file

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Header></Header>
    <main>
      <section v-if="this.showAlert">
        <b-alert show variant="success">
          <h4 class="alert-heading">Well done!</h4>
          <p>
            This web-app was made by Gabriel Nunes, he did it all by himself.
            All these buttons and headers that you saw on the app, was made by
            him too.
          </p>
          <hr />
          <p class="mb-0">
            If you need anything from him, please contact via social netorks.
            Social networks:
            <img
              :src="this.showImg.facebook.src"
              :width="this.showImg.facebook.width"
              :height="this.showImg.facebook.height"
            />
          </p>
          <p class="mb-1">
            <img
              :src="this.showImg.github.src"
              :width="this.showImg.github.width"
              :height="this.showImg.github.height"
            />
          </p>
        </b-alert>
      </section>

      <section v-if="!this.showAlert">
        <b-alert show variant="secondary">
          <h4 class="alert-heading">Well done!</h4>
          <p>
            Aww yeah, you successfully read this important alert message. This
            example text is going to run a bit longer so that you can see how
            spacing within an alert works with this kind of content.
          </p>
          <hr />
          <p class="mb-0">
            Whenever you need to, be sure to use margin utilities to keep things
            nice and tidy.
          </p>
        </b-alert>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./Header.vue";
import { pathImgObj } from "../../utils.js";
export default {
  components: {
    Header,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showImg: {},
      showAlert: Boolean,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.showAlert = confirm("Are you sure about this?");
    this.showImg = { ...pathImgObj };
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Utils file js

```
export const config = {
  home: 'Home',
  anime: 'Animes',
  faq: 'FAQs',
  about: 'About'
}
export const pathImgObj = {
  facebook: {
    src: `./assets/img/facebook.png`,
    width: '30px',
    height: '30px'
  },
  github: {
    src: `./assets/img/github.png`,
    height: '30px',
    width: '30px'
  }
}
```

Expected result: get the src, width and height from utils file and pass it to my About.vue
How can I do this?

My results:
[image: Img not found]

Comment: Can you give an example of your file structure as that will help figure out if the paths are correct

Comment: Yeah, of course, here it is
https://prnt.sc/13bik3h

Comment: @GabrielNunes Move you're `assets` directory from the `src` directory to the `public` directory.

Comment: Omg, it worked >< thank you!

Comment: But why? I didn't understand

Comment: Shouldn’t your relative path be `../assets/images/…`, since you’re using it in a VueJS file that is in a different directory? Also, there’s already documentation on how static assets are handled: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules

Comment: I already tried that approach but didn't work as well, or my approach isn't right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a URL is `require`d or `import`ed, Webpack processes the URL, and decides what to do with it. For image URLs, Webpack finds the image, transforms it (e.g., image scaling and optimization), puts the result in an output directory, and returns the result's URL (e.g., `dist/img/foo.abcd123.jpg`).

`vue-loader` automatically `require`s only *static* URLs of `<img>.src`:

```html
<img src="@/assets/foo.jpg"> ✅

<img :src="'@/assets/' + imgUrl1"> ❌
<img :src="imgUrl2"> ❌
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      imgUrl1: 'foo.jpg',
      imgUrl2: '@/assets/foo.jpg',
    }
  }
}
```

Dynamically bound `<img>.src` must be manually `require`d either in the binding value or in the `<script>` block:

```html
<img :src="require('@/assets/' + imgUrl1)"> ✅
<img :src="require(imgUrl2)"> ✅
<img :src="imgUrl3"> ✅
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      imgUrl1: 'foo.jpg',
      imgUrl2: '@/assets/foo.jpg',
      imgUrl3: require('@/assets/foo.jpg'),
    }
  }
}
```

Since the URLs in the utils file are dynamically bound in the template, `vue-loader` does not `require` them, and thus they're treated as [static assets](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling)  in [`public/`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder). For example, a static URL of `./assets/foo.jpg` refers to `public/assets/foo.jpg`.